# How to receive json data from view send to HTML in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I create a multiple select form by MultipleChoiceFiel. I want to choose option and load information of that option from database. I pass fruit_id via ajax to view to get object fruit, how can I receive json_string data from view send to my HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" selected >Select fruit</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Orange</option>
  <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="4">Banana</option>
</select>
```

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        fruit_id = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '{% url 'view' %}',
            data: {
                   'fruit_id': fruit_id
                  },
            success: function(result) {
                    document.write(result)
                    }
    });
  });
});
```

view.py

```
def view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
 if request.is_ajax():
    id = request.POST.get('fruit_id')
    fruit = Fruit.object.get(pk=id);
    data = {}
    data['fruit_name'] = fruit.name
    data['fruit_code'] = fruit.code
    data['fruit_address'] = fruit.address
    json_string = json.dumps(data)
 return JsonResponse({'json_string': json_string})
```

Comment: This can't possibly work at all. The `url` tag is rendered on the server, so `fruit_id` can't have a value and you would get a NoReverseMatch error.

Comment: but when I alert `$("#mySelect option:selected").val()` it displayed id of fruit so why I pass that value to `url` wrong?

Comment: I just said; the URL tag is rendered on the server, ages before the JS can run. Understanding the difference between server-side and client-side code is pretty fundamental to web development.

Comment: oh I understood so in my situation may be have solution or not?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of solutions. For a start, take fruit_id out of the URL altogether, and just get it from the POST data inside your view.

Comment: I have already updated my code. Can you help me check it and how can I receive json_string data from view send to my HTML?